# Pytorch why is .float() needed here for RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double

Tags: python, pytorch

Simple question, i wanted to experiment with the simplest possible network, but i kept running into `RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double` unless i casted `data` into `.float()` (see below code with comment)

What i dont understand is, why is this casting needed? `data` is already a `torch.float64` type. Whys the explicit re-casting in the `output = model(data.float())` line needed?

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

# =============================================================================
# Simplest Example
# =============================================================================
X, y = make_classification()
X, y = torch.tensor(X), torch.tensor(y)
print("X Shape :{}".format(X.shape))
print("y Shape :{}".format(y.shape))

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(X.shape[1], 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
    
device = torch.device("cuda") 
lr = 1
batch_size = 32
gamma = 0.7
epochs = 14
args = {'log_interval': 10, 'dry_run':False}

kwargs = {'batch_size': batch_size}
kwargs.update({'num_workers': 1,
               'pin_memory': True,
               'shuffle': True},
                 )

model = Net().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=1, gamma=gamma)

my_dataset = TensorDataset(X,y) # create dataset
train_loader = DataLoader(my_dataset,**kwargs) #generate dataloader

cross_entropy_loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    ## Train step ##
    model.train()
    
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data.float()) #HERE: why is .float() needed here?
        loss = cross_entropy_loss(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % args['log_interval'] == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))
            if args['dry_run']:
                break
    
    scheduler.step()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyTorch, 64-bit floating point corresponds to `torch.float64` or `torch.double`.
While, 32-bit floating point corresponds to `torch.float32` or `torch.float`.

Thus,

> `data` is already a `torch.float64` type

i.e. `data` is a 64 floating point type (`torch.double`).

By casting it using `.float()`, you convert it into 32-bit floating point.

```
a = torch.tensor([[1., -1.], [1., -1.]], dtype=torch.double)
print(a.dtype)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
# torch.float64
print(a.float().dtype)                                                                                                                                
# torch.float32
```

Check different [data types](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) in PyTorch.

[image]

Comment: hey @kharshit, thanks! how would you recommend i modify the setup then? Should i immediately cast it all to float? or is double a better choice?

Comment: it's okay to cast model inputs to float, you can read more in the [github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2138)